# Emacs and Gnu Screen Causing Line Wrap Problems

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen, terminal.app

I have gnuscreen on with multiple "tabs" open. Emacs is on tab 0.

When I tab to a different screen and return to Emacs, the lines do not wrap properly anymore. They blend into each other. If I have a vertical split open in Emacs, the two views blend into each other as if the bar in the middle fails to constrain the line wraps.

How do I prevent this? This is in Terminal.app and the only solution I've found is to force a redraw by dragging the corner slightly. That's not a good long term solution.

Comment: `C-a C-l` is another way to force a redraw.